# Multi-colored data bound Pushpin template?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I am writing an app for WP7/WP8 for tracking buses. 
This is the template that I am currently using for a bus stop pushpin -

```
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="StopPin" TargetType="my:Pushpin" >
    <Ellipse Fill="Green" Width="10" Height="10" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

How do I change this template so that I can color the stop circle based on the routes that
are currently serviced at the stop? Is there a way I can databind the ellipse color to a list of colors?

Comment: There's already a default converter between string => color.  That's why you can type the text "Green" in the property and in the object you get an instance of System.Windows.Media.Color (or whatevs).  So all you need to do is have a public string property on your pushpin and use color names that match the properties here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx

Comment: But I want to add multiple colors. For eg, If I say "Blue,Green", I want to circle to be half green and half blue. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll have to code it.  You're moving beyond databinding into the world of custom controls.  I'd suggest pushing this until you are more comfortable with working in the platform.

Comment: @Will - thanks for the advice! I'll get the rest of the functionality done before attempting ths.